# How to debug React Native App with Flipper?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, fbflipper

I use React Native Debugger but it has its limitation so can anyone guide me with the bare minimum on how to start debugging using Facebook Flipper and even is it worth it to use?

*My main requirement is to be able to monitor the Network and Database of React Native app.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please go through below points for debug react native app using flipper.

1. React Native version should be latest.
2. Install desktop app for flipper in window and mac(If you are using mac than may be ask for some permission).
3. Open flipper and run react native project.
4. Finally If you see in flipper than you project dom tree is showing in react dev tool.Below I attached screenshot for react dev tools using flipper.
   Note:- Flipper provide more feature like inspect network request, layout, you can check react native log and native logs(for ios and android).It is more easy just follow above steps.

[image]